# How to pass current variable from php blade foreach to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, laravel-blade

So I'm using blade templates, and I need to get the id of the question which I click on, but from what I have now I keep logically getting the last one, which was in the end of `@foreach`.

Here's php:

```
@section('content')
      <div class="kappa">
          @foreach($questions as $question)
          <p><a class= "questions">{{$question->id}}. {{$question->string}}</a></p><br>
          @endforeach
      </div>
@stop
```

And here's script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $somevar = <?php echo ($question->id) ?>;
    $(".questions").click(function(){
        $(".kappa").text($somevar);
    });
});
```

How could I assign `$somevar` the value of the id of that `@foreach` element which I click on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `data-*` attributes, take a look at **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** :

```
<div class="kappa">
    @foreach($questions as $question)
       <p><a data-question-id="{{$question->id}}" class="questions">{{$question->id}}. {{$question->string}}</a></p><br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And retrieve the value in js using `data()` :

```
$(".questions").click(function(){
    $(".kappa").text($(this).data('question-id'));
});
```

Hope this helps.